# How to get phone number of an android CDMA phone?

Tags: android, api, cdma

The TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() works on GSM phones, but not CDMA phones. Is it possible to get the phone number of a CDMA phone through android API calls at all? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used the following on a Motorola Droid and HTC EVO 4G which are both CDMA.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Make sure you are requesting the correct permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: One of my users reports that he uses htc evo on sprint and this method doesn't work.

Comment: I've confirmed that this method works on a stock Sprint HTC EVO 4G running Android 2.2.

Comment: I think it depends on your provider, not the phone or the Android version whether this works.

Answer (score 2):

Although the method suggested might work, some carriers (I believe it's their choice) do not provide this number, returning null instead.

Returning null is stated in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html
(scroll down to the method's documentation).

Here is a link for a possible work-around:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1110#c5