# In android how to get phone number of caller (i mean our own phone no)?

Tags: android

**

> how to get phone no of caller (i mean
>   our own phone no)?

**I got the reciever phone number but not getting caller phone no.If any idea please tell me?

Comment: What's with all this obscure formatting in your question? And what do you mean "caller"? You want to find out your own phone number when you receive a phone call? Or that of the person calling?!

Comment: it looks like you have a few questions for which you're satisfied with the answers other folks have given you, but you didn't mark that you accepted their answers.  I suggest you review your past questions, and mark answers as accepted, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

[How to get the phone number of the phone in android code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930424/how-to-get-the-phone-number-of-the-phone-in-android-code)

and

[How to get phone number of an android CDMA phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696489/how-to-get-phone-number-of-an-android-cdma-phone)

Comment: i GOT SATISFIED WITH UR ANS AND LINK.THANK U

Comment: Great.  How about an up vote, instead of a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

to get ur phone no following code is used

```
         final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
           String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

and add uses-permission for

```
 android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: dude atleast read the question befor you answer , its asking about getting the phone no. of the caller and not of self....